# Kiwi reporting to JIRA issue

Tags: jira, kiwi-tcms

I want Kiwi to report bugs to JIRA. I have configured the JIRA bugtracker in the config page. I go to my test run an click on report. I select my JIRA issue tracker and click on report. Then I get no response. I check the Chrome's console, it shows JS error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rc' of undefined testrun_actions.js:460 ". Kiwi is 7.2 runnig in a docker conrainer. 
How can I make this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. Maybe a couple of them. The UI should be more tolerant to these errors and inform the user what's going on.

As to why this happens I can't tell. This appears to be reported in 
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/1333 which speaks about a TC text with 3.5KB size. This is quite a lot of text and depending on what JIRA accepts there may not be anything we can do about it.

Will follow up on the GitHub issue. If the original question isn't related please leave a comment indicating so.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your answer.